# Keyboard caret covers my EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my register screen. When I focused on confirmPass EditText, the soft keyboard covered my keyboard.  Note the caret covered the "q" key and I can't touch it. What's the best solution for this case?

[image]

The screen XML:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="@string/nameHint" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="@string/emailHint"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text="" 
        android:hint="@string/passwordHint" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/confirmPassword"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text="" 
        android:hint="@string/confirmPasswordHint"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/register" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in your android manifest file for this activity.

Comment: it doesn't help, it still cover my EditText

Comment: I think margin Bottom for your layout will work.